# Java. Is there an easy way to sequentialize a multithreaded app to make debugging easier?

Tags: java

I have a spring-mvc app that has a lot of different threads that do different things.
I would love if I could make the program (and the logs) be more deterministic. (that everything gets executed in the same order always).

Maybe there is an easy way of doing this.

Or at least, you have a suggestion how to debug this kind of multithreaded apps???

Answer (score 3):

For logging, you can include the thread ID, and then filter to look at just one thread at a time.

Thread context switches are up to the OS scheduler, and amongst other things, depend on what other processes running. The only way to make sure your threads run in a particular order would be with concurrency signaling mechanisms, which you should not do unless you have a good reason. Important results of your app should be deterministic (otherwise, it's a race condition). But order of interwoven thread execution should vary.

Answer (score 1):

Dane's idea is interesting, but I would recommend against that as a way of debugging multi-threaded code.

Why?

Because logging is likely to alter the properties of the code you are trying to debug.

And so is using a conventional debugger.

In fact, there isn't an easy way of debugging multi-threaded code.

My advice would be:

1. Try to implement your code using high level concurrency constructs from the Java SE libraries.
2. Pay special attention to making sure that objects and data structures that are shared by multiple threads are properly synchronized.
3. When you run into problems, try to work out what is happening by *reasoning* about the problem.
4. Try and find a static code analyzer that can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use ExecutorService in java.util.concurrent package. This is a much easier way of handling threads in a multithreaded application.

If you just want to run a single thread.
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

You can refer to an example from here
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_concurrency/concurrency_newsinglethreadexecutor.htm

later if you want to run the same program with multiple threads. Use
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads);
It Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue.

Ex:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_concurrency/concurrency_newfixedthreadpool.htm

For more clarification refer to this. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html